# how to reload jquery plugin after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am using the infinite ajax scroll plugin.  It works until a user posts a new comment.

I have a comment form, when a user posts a new comment it reloads all comments and pagination, but the infinite scroll link is no longer visible.

How do I reload the plugin?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#comment').on('submit',function(e) {

$.ajax({
    url:'pagination.php',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'HTML',
    success:function(data, response){

$('#comments').html(data);
reload jquery-ias.js <------ reload here


    },
```

Comment: If you need to reload an entire Javascript file, it's because there is something wrong with your approach. Why don't you ask to the server for the html of the new posts only? You send a timestamp and the server returns all the new comments since then and the timestamp of the last comment. You can check it for every 20-360 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option to reload the plugin:

```
function setupIAS() {
  ias && $.ias('destroy');
  ias = $.ias({
    container:  '#container',
    item:       'p',
    pagination: '#pagination',
    next:       '.next'
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  setupIAS();

 $('#comment').on('submit',function(e) {

     $.ajax({
        url:'pagination.php',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success:function(data, response) {

            $('#comments').html(data);
            setupIAS();
        }
     })
});
```